# preserve ModalBottomSheet state

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

In a StatefulWidget, I'd like to create a showModalBottomSheet with ChoiceChip. However, I want the ChoiceChip status to be preserved when the modalsheet is closed.
I mean the 'selected' property in ChoiceChip widget this is my code snippets , I appreciate your assistance.

```
class CustomFilterChip extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chipName;

  CustomFilterChip(this.chipName);

  @override
  State<CustomFilterChip> createState() => _CustomFilterChipState();
}

class _CustomFilterChipState extends State<CustomFilterChip> {
  bool status = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FilterChip(
      
      label: Text(widget.chipName),
      selected: status,
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[50],
      selectedColor: kCustomGreen,
      onSelected: (selected) {
        setState(() {
          statusHere = !statusHere;
         
        });
      },
    );
  }
}


showModalBottomSheet(
 context: context,
  builder: (ctx){
    return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                'select your filter chip'
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.sp),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Wrap(
                  spacing: 25,
                  children: [
                    CustomFilterChip('chip1')
                    CustomFilterChip('chip2')
                    CustomFilterChip('chip3')
                   
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If that the case, you need to have the main instance of 'selected' variable inside the widget from where you are calling the bottom sheet to open and then pass the value of 'selected' variable to the widget which is being rendered inside the bottom sheet.